# How to make an unordered list "stay" once the header is hovered?

Tags: css

In the attached pen, I want to make my code so that once "Choose a Design" is hovered over by the user, the options stays, not disappearing immediately after the user moves the mouse away.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGNGdR

This is what I tried:

```
nav[role=navigation] {
    display:none;
}

.select:hover + nav[role=navigation] {
    display:block;
}
```

P.S: I am not allowed to make changes to the HTML.
The HTML is actually a part of the default design of CSS Zen Garden.

Comment: I had made an edit to the title, but I misunderstood the question. I've reverted it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is add the `:hover` to the parent element instead of it's sibling.

```css
.design-selection nav[role=navigation]        { display:none; }
.design-selection:hover nav[role=navigation]  { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="design-selection" id="design-selection">
  <h3 class="select">Select a Design:</h3>
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a> by <a href="http://andrewlohman.com/" class="designer-name">Andrew Lohman</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/220/" class="design-name">Garments</a> by <a href="http://danielmall.com/" class="designer-name">Dan Mall</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/219/" class="design-name">Steel</a> by <a href="http://steffen-knoeller.de" class="designer-name">Steffen Knoeller</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/218/" class="design-name">Apothecary</a> by <a href="http://trentwalton.com" class="designer-name">Trent Walton</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/217/" class="design-name">Screen Filler</a> by <a href="http://elliotjaystocks.com/" class="designer-name">Elliot Jay Stocks</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/216/" class="design-name">Fountain Kiss</a> by <a href="http://jeremycarlson.com" class="designer-name">Jeremy Carlson</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/215/" class="design-name">A Robot Named Jimmy</a> by <a href="http://meltmedia.com/" class="designer-name">meltmedia</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/214/" class="design-name">Verde Moderna</a> by <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/" class="designer-name">Dave Shea</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely useful. Please edit and explain why this works and how this works.Thanks

Comment: I added a small explanation

Comment: It wasn't working for you because when your mouse moves outside of the `.select`, it went back to it's original state `display: none`. by adding hover to the parent element it accounts for everything

Answer (score 1):

i added a parent `div` and i gave it the class.

```css
nav[role=navigation] {
  display:none;
}

.select:hover nav[role=navigation] {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="design-selection" id="design-selection">
  <div class="select">
    <h3>Select a Design:</h3>
    <nav role="navigation">
     <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="/221/" class="design-name">Mid Century Modern</a> by      <a href="http://andrewlohman.com/" class="designer-name">Andrew Lohman</a>
     </li>     <li>
      <a href="/220/" class="design-name">Garments</a> by      <a href="http://danielmall.com/" class="designer-name">Dan Mall</a>
     </li>     <li>
      <a href="/219/" class="design-name">Steel</a> by      <a href="http://steffen-knoeller.de" class="designer-name">Steffen Knoeller</a>
     </li>     <li>
      <a href="/218/" class="design-name">Apothecary</a> by      <a href="http://trentwalton.com" class="designer-name">Trent Walton</a>
     </li>     <li>
      <a href="/217/" class="design-name">Screen Filler</a> by      <a href="http://elliotjaystocks.com/" class="designer-name">Elliot Jay Stocks</a>
     </li>     <li>
      <a href="/216/" class="design-name">Fountain Kiss</a> by      <a href="http://jeremycarlson.com" class="designer-name">Jeremy Carlson</a>
     </li>     <li>
      <a href="/215/" class="design-name">A Robot Named Jimmy</a> by      <a href="http://meltmedia.com/" class="designer-name">meltmedia</a>
     </li>     <li>
      <a href="/214/" class="design-name">Verde Moderna</a> by      <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/" class="designer-name">Dave Shea</a>
     </li>     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It disappeared once mouse is moved away from header. I think It should stay as per question.